# c# Create List<object> from array with different Property Names

Tags: c#, arrays, generics

I would like to know if it's possible to create a generic list from an array, where the properties are different, both in the amount and the names. I've seen a number of posts that could do this with the same fields in each object, but none where there are different property names and there's a different number of them.

It feels like there should be a way of "mapping" one property to another somehow when populating my List..

I have access to a web service - that I have no control over - that gives me a number of properties for a given object; all are poorly named and some are irrelevant.

I am currently using a foreach loop to cycle through all the items in my array, and then adding to my List using the class constructor of the objects in my generic list.

If I have a large number of items returned in my array, this method starts to feel really dirty and I'd like to know if there's a more elegant solution.

To elaborate, suppose I have an array of objects, with the properties below, passed to me in the web service that I have no control over:

- HorribleName1 (string)
- HorribleName2 (string)
- HorribleName3 (DateTime)
- HorribleName4 (int)

but my local class has the following properties...

- FirstName (string)
- LastName (string)
- DateOfBirth (DateTime)

I know HorribleName1 is the first name of the person, and HorribleName2 is the last name. I also know that HorribleName3 is their date of birth, and that HorribleName4 is irrelevant.

Is there a better way of creating my generic list than this:

```
List<myPerson> myList = new List<myPerson>();       
foreach (ArrayObject person in HorribleArray)
{
    myList.Add(new myPerson(HorribleName1, HorribleName2, HorribleName3));
}
```

Comment: `HorribleName3 (DateTime)` is their birthday and not 4 I assume. And your way is.. working.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I tried to make that clear but didn't check what I'd posted well enough apparently... :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's purely aesthetic, but you could use LINQ to project your data like so:

```
List<myPerson> myList = (from person in HorribleArray
                         select new Person()
                         {
                             FirstName = person.horribleName1, 
                             Lastname = person.horribleName2, 
                             Birthday = person.HorribleName3
                         }).ToList();
```

Indeed, as Jim suggests, you can still use the same constructor syntax instead of using the object initialiser.

```
List<myPerson> myList = (from person in HorribleArray
                         select new Person(person.horribleName1, person.horribleName2, person.HorribleName3)).ToList();
```

However, it is my personal opinion that, especially when projecting properties that change names, object initialisers make the code much more readable.

Following Jim's comment, I agree that you might not want to make properties public to use initialisers, so yet another option would be to use named arguments:

```
List<myPerson> myList = (from person in HorribleArray
                         select new Person(
                             firstName: person.horribleName1,
                             lastName: person.horribleName2, 
                             birthday: person.HorribleName3)).ToList();
```

Comment: You might consider using the constructor syntax that the OP uses. That is `select new Person(HorribleName1, HorribleName2, HorribleName3)`

Comment: Thanks gentlemen. I'll mark as answer as soon as I've tested on my own data.

Comment: I agree that object initializers make code more readable. Unfortunately, they require that property setters be `public`, which raises a whole host of other issues. I still haven't decided which balance of good vs. evil I prefer.

Comment: This works exactly as I'd like. Surprisingly though, it didn't appear to be any quicker than using the foreach loop, even when I had a sub list of child objects in my class.